# Inflating class into a xml file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Recently I was working in a Android project I need to inflating my class into my .xml file and my class is

```
public class FacebookWebView extends WebView {

    public FacebookWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

And my XML code is

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FacebookNewWrapper" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.example.tainfal.FacebookWebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.Tinfoil.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/webview_top_progress_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/webview_top_progress_bar_top_margin" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custome_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Log cat error is....

```
  02-06 23:58:42.773: E/Trace(22653): error opening trace file: No such    file or directory (2)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653)java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.example.tainfal/com.example.tainfal.MainActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.example.tainfal.FacebookWebView
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-06 23:58:43.013: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
```

When I run my project it stopped.
I am new in Android developing I have no experince about inflating a class in XML file how I can I solve this problem.

Comment: There should be more of the stack trace below what you have, such as a "Caused by" trace.

Comment: no there is nothing about that.@CommonsWare

Comment: Yeah, there should be more to the stack trace. This occurs when the `View` cant be instantiated. I'd guess it's an error in the `FacebookWebView`

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#subclassview):

> To allow the Android Developer Tools to interact with your view, at a
>   minimum you must provide a constructor that takes a Context and an
>   AttributeSet object as parameters.This constructor allows the layout editor to create and edit an instance of your view.

So you need a constructor with two arguments for `FacebookWebView`:

```
 public FacebookWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context,attrs);        
 }
```

otherwise LogCat will report with following exception:

```
 02-07 00:45:49.879  23086-23086/android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication, PID: 23086
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication/android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.sof.q28372281.FacebookWebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.sof.q28372281.FacebookWebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
        at android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at android.stackoverflow.com.sofapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time i have solved it.I have to add this two constractor

```
 public FacebookWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public FacebookWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```